# Get users which has specific role ONLY - Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rolify

There is a dropdown which displays the list of sales reps which is defined as follows.

```
<%= f.select :sales_rep_id,
          User.with_role(:sales_rep).order(:email).map { |u| [u.email, u.id] },
          { include_blank: true },
          class: 'form-control' %>
```

The sales_rep users may also have other roles such as developer.

I need to hide the **sales rep users who have the developer role** as well.

Something like

```
User.where.not(has_role?(:developer)).with_role :sales_rep
```

Any idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please describe the relationship between users and roles? What's the SQL that the `with_role` scope generates?

Comment: The relation is that sales rep person can also be a developer. I need to pick the sales rep that are not developer. The query that is executed for with_role is as follows SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users_roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE (((roles.name = 'sales_rep') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
non_developers = User.enabled.order(:email).without_role(:developer)
sales_reps = non_developers.with_role(:sales_rep)
```

worked like a charm...

Comment: This is a bit weird no? You un-accepted my answer to accept your own answer. I did take the time to help you find the answer, you did not even upvote my answer. Furthermore: your answer is incomplete, you do not define `without_role` so any reader will still have to read my answer to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not best answer but you can use it if necessary.

```
User.with_role(:sales_rep) - User.with_role(:developer)
```

Answer (score 0):

So

```
developers = User.with_role(:developer)
sales_people = User.with_role(:sales_rep)
```

To exclude one group from the other, as efficiently as possible, I would do something like the following:

```
User.with_role(:sales_rep).where.not(id: User.with_role(:developer).select(:id).map(&:id))
```

This should return the wanted set, now we could improve it a little bit:

In your `User` class add a method

```
def self.without_role(role)
  where.not(id: User.with_role(role).ids)
end
```

Note that `User.pluck(:id)` or the short version `.ids` is in result identical to `User.select(:id).amp(&:id)` but a lot more efficient as it will not instantiate a complete `User` object.

And then you could write

```
User.without_role(:developer).with_role(:sales_rep)
```

Comment: The first one is working but the improved code is not working. If i run User.with_role(role).pluck(:id) inside the self.without_role(role) method, it is returning an empty array.

Comment: The query that is run   when  i run User.with_role(role).pluck(:id) inside the self.without_role(role) method is as follows.  

User.with_role(:developer)

  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users_roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users"."enabled" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'sales_rep') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL))) AND (((roles.name = 'developer') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["enabled", "t"]]

Comment: Which rails version are you using? Because `pluck` has changed/improved over the versions? I am testing with rails 4.2.11.1 (since your tag says ruby-on-rails-4)

Comment: Ha, I just learned there is an even shorter version: in rails 4 you can also write `.ids` which would do the same. Weird `pluck` should also work in rails 3, so still curious which version you are using.

Comment: Oh maybe it is not `pluck`, maybe it is the order? What happens if you write `User.without_role(:developer).with_role(:sales_rep)`?

Comment: The issue was with the order. Changing the order did the trick

Comment: Ok. Adapted my answer accordingly. Maybe the full command is then a more readable/clearer option, use it as you prefer.